# How to make reloadData less glitchy (visually)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Finally I got my custom UITableCells to work. While playing with the app I noticed a weird bug: the rows flickered for a split second when the view loads.

This is caused by `[self.tableView reloadData]`, because if I disable it the problem disappears.

Currently, this piece of code is in `viewDidAppear`. It is there because the tableView is a profile manager, which works this way: press `+` button > write out profiles > save profiles > go back to table using segue > profiles should now appear.

Also, my program has darkmode in it, and for rows specifically, the checks for darkmode are done inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath` because I wasn't able to figure out a way to do this differently (where do I retrieve the cells if not where I generate them?). This means that for darkmode to apply, the tables need to be refreshed.

So, question is, what is the correct approach here? How should I handle the table reload without having the annoying visual glitch and while keeping darkmode changes apply on the fly (without having to relaunch the app)?

Comment: do that in  `viewWillAppear:` instead of  `viewDidAppear`

Comment: @arturdev Yes, that worked. Please write an answer so I can close the question.

Answer (score 0):

Do that in `viewWillAppear:` instead of `viewDidAppear:`.